# How to get country name based on ip

Tags: hadoop, geolocation, ip, apache-pig

I have a list of IP address. I need to assign a country to each IP.
For example http://www.ip2nation.com/ provides this service. 
I have found some databases for IP2Country, but how do I integrate it with pig?

Input:

```
14.59.63.28
145.89.87.211
54.27.253.89
98.201.50.22
116.48.29.143
145.89.87.211
20.109.204.65
20.109.204.65
```

Expected output:

```
14.59.63.28     country1
145.89.87.211   country2
54.27.253.89    country3
98.201.50.22    country4
116.48.29.143   country5
145.89.87.211   country2
20.109.204.65   country6
20.109.204.65   country6
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get Extract of Database of IP and country name from that database.
Then use that Extracted data to perform join with your data which you streaming.

I will straight forward join. To get better performance you can check for replicated join in Pig 
http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref1.html#Replicated+Joins

Comment: i have randomly generated IP addresses, few of them not in the range of database IP addresses(not matches),so i think joining is not possible...right?